# What effects does being on the high ground have?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I'm going to hope there is some benefit to being on higher ground but I'm not sure what. how much does elevation increase affect? if there is any benefit to say shooting from behind the hill. How close does the enemy have to be to lose the benefit? Are there any benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being on higher elevation allow your range units (magic, crossbow, etc...) to fire further out.

Melee units has to charge up the hill and may exhaust them more than if it was flat or even downhill.

Being on hill also let you see further out through fog of war and prevent the hill itself from becoming a blind spot. You can easily spot this while in deployment phase by moving units around a bit.

Keep in mind, flying units don't really care about hill and can swoop to the top with minimum fussing.